# How to logout in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am junior in app development.
I just tried to logout in react native small project.
Then after I click the logout button, when I click the back button (Android device button), it goes to former screen again. Of course, the API doesn't work. In this case, how can I prevent to go back to the former screen?

```
  logout = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('WelcomePage')
  }
```

Comment: try to clear your navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`reset`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#reset) instead of `navigate`.

> The reset method lets us replace the navigator state with a new state:
>
> ```
> navigation.reset({
>   index: 0,
>   routes: [{ name: 'Profile' }],
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

#### React Navigation provides [createSwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/switch-navigator/) with Authentication in mind

#### [Authentication Example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/auth-flow)